# Getting rstudio to work with windows python virtual env?

Tags: python, r, windows, rstudio, virtualenv

I'm on windows 10 and have successfully installed python and a virtual env.
I can activate it `.\v3\Scripts\activate`. On rstudio I created a new project and in the .Rprofile I add this line `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:/Users/usr1/pyvirt/v3/Scripts/python")` however when I open Rstudio and run `reticulate::py_config()` I get this error msg.

```
Error in py_discover_config(required_module, use_environment) :  Python specified in RETICULATE_PYTHON (C:/Users/usr1/pyvirt/v3/Scripts/python) does not exist
```

but I can clearly see python.exe in this directory and also can activate it.
any clue as to what else I can try? thanks.

Comment: Try adding the `.exe` extension to the env var

Comment: @HongOoi I tried that, but now the error is, python39.dll - Access is denied.